# Typescript: define interface property value as keyof another property in the same interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define some interface for object containing a dictionnary and defaultKey properties.
What I'm trying to do is define an interface that allow me to force defaultKey to be a valid key in the dictionnary property:
Here's the idea:

```js
interface I{
    dictionnary?: {
        [k:string]:any
    }
    defaultKey?: Extract<keyof this['dictionnary'], string>
}
```

Here's an example of object that could use such interface:

```
interface Theme { color: string}
interface Themes {
  availableThemes: {[k:string]:Theme}
  defaultTheme: Extract<keyof this['availableThemes'], string>
}
const themes:Themes = {
  availableThemes: {
    red: {color: 'red'},
    green: {color: 'green'},
    blue: {color: 'blue'},
  },
  defaultTheme: 'red' // <- validate that red is a key for an available theme
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a proper way to achieve this ?

Comment: No, there is no specific type in TypeScript that works that way.  You could write a *generic* type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wERY2N). Please provide a [mre] demonstrating how you'd like to use your `I` type and someone could show you the analog with generics.

Comment: @jcalz hope the example is more explicit

Comment: What's a `Theme`?

Comment: Theme is just a sample config dictionnary for the example let's make it a {color: 'string'}

Comment: (Okay, please [edit] the code to show that.)  The generic version would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9PYow).  Does that work for you or am I missing something?

Comment: this is a step in right direction but I would prefer not to use a function to make it work, just an interface or a Type.

Comment: As I said, there is no specific type that works that way.  So an answer could either say "this is impossible, go away" or "this is impossible, here is the way people do this" where the latter version is with a function.  What do you want to see here?

Comment: Hey I know that this is closed, but maybe you were looking to do something like this?
`enum ThemeIds {
  red = "red",
  green = "green",
  blue = "blue",
}

interface Theme {
  color: string;
}

interface Themes {
  availableThemes: { [ key in ThemeIds]: Theme }; 
  defaultTheme: keyof typeof ThemeIds;
}

const themes: Themes = {
  availableThemes: {
    red: { color: "red" },
    green: { color: "green" },
    blue: { color: "blue" },
  },
  defaultTheme: "red",
};`

Comment: ( It is super hard to write code in this kind of comments )

Comment: @NicolásJuárezNuño thanks for your comment, but the problem is that i don't know in advance the keys of Themes so I can't make an enum out of them.